# Attaching 2 applications

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

I have **Program A** running with some variables. I wish to have a second program - **Program B** - that can be run seperately and when run will attach itself to **Program A**. From within **Program B** I'd like to be able to modify and change certain variables in **Program A**. Both programs have been written by me.

I have seen this happen with the likes of Dwarf Fortress and Dwarf Therapist which allows you to change various variables in one program which will make the changes in another.

I assume you setup an area of shared memory and reference the variables with pointers but is this possible with C#.Net and if so - how?

Comment: Can you write the code for both programs?

Comment: @MatthewWatson - Yes I can. I'll update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [memory-mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) to create an area of memory, shared between applications.

But the cleaner and more reliable solution would be to introduce an API in your program, so that other programs could interact with it. You can use WCF, Thrift, or other technologies for that.

Comment: I agree - I'd go for [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms731082.aspx) too. [Here's a simple example](http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2007/04/14/a-truely-simple-example-to-get-started-with-wcf.aspx), but you'd want to change the `NetTcpBinding()` to a `NetNamedPipeBinding()` in that sample.